# lucene: space requirements for optimising the database?

Tags: optimization, lucene

It is my understanding that there are several options when it comes to database optimisation in Lucene:

- optimise the whole thing into one segment, space hungry by at least 2× ?
- optimise into several segments
- remove deleted entries — [`expungeDeletes()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#expungeDeletes%28boolean%29), without changing the number of segments?

Consider that a database is not held on a platter disc ([mfs](http://mdoc.su/o/mfs) is in use).  Do each of these operations have some bound on space requirements?

I noticed that `expungeDeletes()` is no longer documented for Lucene 4.6.0 — has it been removed?  I'm coming from Lucene 3.0.2 / December 2011, although I'm open to upgrading to 4.6 sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Manual optimization methods have now been removed in favour of *Tiered Merge Policy*. You may [read about this in the blog post](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/02/visualizing-lucenes-segment-merges.html) of one of the authors of Lucene. In short, merge will happen automatically as it is believed that the algorithm (which knows the internal state of the index) will do a better job than the user.

p.s. I think you need to get the nomenclature right. There's no such thing as "database" in Lucene (you probably meant index?)

Comment: That's a good start, but it doesn't address the question all that much — how do I ensure Lucene won't exceed my limited disc space?  Moreover, I have several separate indices on the same disc, so, if they're now merged automatically and at random times, then I'd need a way to ensure that they won't be doing so during the same re-index run by my app.

Comment: Instead of expecting Lucene to fit into given partition, you should rather [be planning](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/.../size-estimator-lucene-solr.xls) for it. Not even databases offer you this sort of feature. Last but not least, disks are cheap (you can get 1Tb disk for around $100 these days and I bet your index is far less than 1T).

Comment: thank you for not reading the question, where it is specifically mentioned that platter discs are not used.

Comment: OK, you got me on this one! Anyway, I still think optimization on edge conditions (when the disk is nearly full) is way too much unpredictable, especially if you run multiple independent indices. I still fail to understand why capacity planning isn't acceptable for you.

Comment: Maybe because it's not reasonable to have to allocate and reserve 2× the size of each index for space that'll be sitting empty 24/7/365, sans the case where all indices happen to have reached the optimisation point, and are actively being optimised?